# Water not coming from outdoor faucet

Tags: plumbing, outdoor, valve, plumbing-fixture, freezing

I have outdoor faucet with frost free hose bib - a Woodford 17. No water is flowing when I try to open the valve.

I did leave a hose timer attached over the winter. No pipes burst, but I'm worried that this could have kept the tap from draining and let ice damage the valve.

How can I determine what's blocking the flow and how to fix it?

Comment: Please post some pictures showing what you are talking about. You say timer, there are a lot of them and I have no clue as to which one you are talking about.

Comment: Is there a shutoff valve upstream that may have also been shutoff for the winter?

Comment: it was ON all the time.

Comment: "Is this a DIY job?" isn't a question we can answer, nor is it on topic here as it's a matter of opinion (usually yours). Please revise to add detail and ask about your problem, not your skills and motivation.

Comment: the knob is work just fine

Comment: That information belongs in your question, not down here.

Comment: The process has been described nicely for you, below. However, whether _you_ can DIY this is a matter for _you_ to determine. We have no idea what your skills are and your ability/willingness to learn new ones. Can _some_ people do this themselves? Sure! Can _you_? Dunno... Since that's the only question you asked, it's off topic.

Comment: Make sense. I agree with you both IsherWood and Freeman. So Removed "Is this a DYI job? "

Answer (score 2):

Woodford provides some very nice [troubleshooting information](https://www.woodfordmfg.com/woodford/Wall_Faucet_Pages/Model-17.html). I would turn off the water supply, then disassemble the unit from the exterior. You may find a part damaged by freezing, or something simply stuck. Clean or replace components as needed.

If that doesn't work you'll probably need to uninstall the unit entirely and either troubleshoot from the interior end or replace it.